# Android app crashes when using different layout folder for tablet

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to make a layout for different screen sizes. I started making a basic layout with some buttons for my Smartphone, after I wanted to have the same layout to be displayed nice on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0. So I followed the instructions as described on the android development website.

I first created the folder 'layout-large' and created a second layout but this time for the tablet, it didnt work. After that I tried with the folder named 'layout-sw600dp' and got the same result, it crashes. I tried using debug mode but for some reason this doesn't work either.

LogCat code is below, I hope someone can help. Kind Regards

```
08-29 10:56:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(6457): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 10:56:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(6457): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.quality_of_life/com.example.quality_of_life.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 10:56:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
08-29 10:56:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
08-29 10:56:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
08-29 10:56:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
08-29 10:56:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-29 10:56:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-29 10:56:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
08-29 10:56:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 10:56:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-29 10:56:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
08-29 10:56:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
08-29 10:56:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-29 10:56:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(6457): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 10:56:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at com.example.quality_of_life.MainActivity.addListenerOnButton(MainActivity.java:29)
08-29 10:56:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at com.example.quality_of_life.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
08-29 10:56:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
08-29 10:56:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
08-29 10:56:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
08-29 10:56:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you lacked some component in your layout. 
Make many screen size, you must be sure that all controls have to be absent in all layout.
Please check your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would post this in a comment but I do not have required reputation!

Firstly could you post the code that is identified by `com.example.quality_of_life.MainActivity.addListenerOnButton(MainActivity.java:29)`. That is the line that is causing your grief and it will probably be apparent what the problem is. When you say that debug mode did not work, did you set a breakpoint in your code, at line 29 of MainActivity?

Are you following guidelines from the Android developer guide? http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Could you also post the skeleton of the /res folder of your project as that will probably contain some clues too.

Comment: I started a new project and copied my code, made the map for tablet again, and now it does work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in my different layouts I used different buttons, my main script was calling for a button that was not there. And so, it crashed. Problem was solved bij hiding the button with android:visibility="gone".

Thank you all for your awnsers